# Thread и jdbc одно соединение

Tags: java, mysql, многопоточность

Не знаю многих нюансов в Java. Интересует, можно ли создать одно соединение с mysql и работать с ним в потоках, или в каждом потоке, нужно создавать дополнительный экземпляр соединения? Более 30 потоков, приводит к ошибке mysql: Too many connections. Снял ограничение mysql, такким образом:

```
set global max_connections = 200;
```

Но это не выход и хотелось бы знать на будущие, как правильно. 
Вот код:

```
   public class ParserMain {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
            // Общее число сообщений
            int total_entries = 12000;
            // Кол-во потоков
            int thread_count = 25;
            // Кол-во записей на поток
            int entries_thread = total_entries / thread_count;
            // Начальный инкремент потока
            int thread_end;
            // Конечный инкремент потока
            int thread_start;

            for (int i = 1; i <= thread_count; ++i) {
                thread_end = i * entries_thread;
                thread_start = thread_end - entries_thread;
                new ParserThread(thread_start, thread_end).start();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ParserThread extends Thread {
        private int jstart;
        private int jend;

        protected Connection conn;
        protected PreparedStatement ps;
        protected Statement st;
        protected ResultSet rs;

        public ParserThread(int jstart, int jend) {
            this.jstart = jstart;
            this.jend = jend;
        }

        public void run() {
            String dbDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
            String dbHost = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?autoReconnect=true";

            try {
                Class.forName(dbDriver);
                conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbHost, "root", "");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Соединений больше чем разрешено на стороне DBMS вы все равно не получите. А правильно, конечно, JDBC пул использовать: c3p0 или HikariCP. Он гибко настраивается на mix-max кол-во соединений и различные таймауты.

Comment: @enzo не использование пула, может привести к потери данных при Insert?

Comment: Я не понимаю что именно  должно "потеряться". SQL запрос или выполняется , или нет. Используйте транзакции для верности.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да можно создать как и многопоточное подключение к БД так и один поток используя синхронизированный метод(Что конечно не рационально с точки зрения производительности)
Тут небольшое лирическое отступление:

> JDBC Drivers - является набор классов Java, который позволяет
>   подключаться к определенной базе данных. JDBC Drivers реализует много
>   интерфейсов JDBC. Когда ваш код использует данный драйвер JDBC, он на
>   самом деле просто использует стандартные  интерфейсы JDBC.Таким
>   образом, вы можете изменять драйвер JDBC не изменяя кода
>
> Connections - после того, как Driver JDBC загружается и
>   инициализируется, необходимо  подключиться к базе данных. Это можно
>   сделать, получив Connection к базе данных через  JDBC API, и
>   загруженный Driver. Вся связь с базой данных происходит через
>   Connection.  Приложение может иметь более одного Connection открытого
>   к базе данных одновременно.
>
> Statements - используете для выполнения запросов и обновлений в базе
>   данных. Есть  несколько различных типов Statements. Каждый Statements
>   соответствует одному запросу  или обновлению.
>
> ResultSets - при выполнении запроса к базе данных вы получите обратно
>   ResultSet. Вы  можете пройти по ResultSet и прочитать результат
>   запроса.

Основной бонус от содержания ConnectionsPool(Пула готовых к работе соеденений) это отсутствие затрат на открытие каждого нового соединения.Такие готовые пулы представляют многие веб контейнеры.Да и написать свою реализацию в общем то обыденная задача.Лимиты с которыми Вы столкнулись вопрос СУБД...
А вот минусы от использования многопоточного подключения это возможные неприятности связанные с параллельной записью или обращением в БД...Как то:

> потерянное обновление (lost update) — при одновременном изменении
>   одного блока данных разными транзакциями, одно из изменений теряется;
>
> «грязное» чтение (dirty read) — чтение данных, добавленных или
>   изменённых транзакцией, которая впоследствии не подтвердится
>   (откатится);
>
> неповторяющееся чтение (non-repeatable read) — при повторном чтении в
>   рамках одной транзакции, ранее прочитанные данные оказываются
>   изменёнными;
>
> фантомное чтение (phantom reads) — Одна транзакция в ходе своего
>   выполнения  несколько раз выбирает множество строк по одним и тем же
>   критериям. Другая  транзакция в интервалах между этими выборками
>   добавляет или удаляет строки или  изменяет столбцы некоторых строк,
>   используемых в критериях выборки первой  транзакции, и успешно
>   заканчивается. В результате получится, что одни и те же выборки  в
>   первой транзакции дают разные множества строк.

Все в принципе лечиться уровнями изоляции транзакции.О чем рекомендую почитать отдельно...

Comment: Душевно! Спасибо за очень развернутый ответ! Выяснилось, что к моей задаче пул, можно и не добавлять)

Comment: Рад помочь ...... )

Answer (score 2):

В классе который инициирует потоки реализуйте кэширующий метод для соединений к БД, аля такой:

```
Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    Connection result;

    if (cnn != null) {
        result = cnn;
    } else {
        result = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    }

    return result;
}
```

далее при создании потоков передавайте им действующее соединение:

```
Connection cnn = getConnection();
ParserThread parserThread = new ParserThread(cnn)
```

ну и + стоит учесть синхронизацию вызовов метода чтобы не было Concurrency исключений